# Changing the Selected Value in the DropDown in Angular 10 with Angular Material Without Changing the List of Selected Choices?

Tags: angular, typescript

New to Angular. Still learning and having understanding problems of a concept.

I want to have a dropdown and have a list of options to choose from. Then, once selected the item will be abbreviated once selected. Example: You select state Ohio - it will turn too OH once selected in the dropdown box. If you go back to the dropdown to choose another state - Ohio will show up. I have tried using a click option, ngModelChange - but not sure how to do this! Please help.

HTML:

```
<section *ngFor="let row of dataSource; let i = index">
<div class="column-state">
    <mat-select (click)="changeFn(state)" placeholder="Choose State" [(ngModel)]="row.state">
      <mat-option [value]="state.full" *ngFor="let type of stateList">
        {{ state.full }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
</section>
```

variable  -

```
hi:any;
stateList= [
{full:'Ohio', short: 'OH'},{ full:'Minnesota', short:'MN'}, {full: 'California', short: 'CA'}];

function tried -
 changeFn(test:any) {
      this.hi = test;
  }
```

Comment: Where do you show the abbreviated value?

Comment: Sorry in the  same dropdown box that you selected the state! So if you select the state, the state abbreviated one would appear only.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, just check if the selected option is equal to the current option

```html
<mat-select placeholder="Choose State" [(ngModel)]="selectedState">
  <mat-option [value]="state.full" *ngFor="let state of stateList">
    {{ selectedState === state.full? state.short : state.full }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And in your component typescript file

```js
export class SelectExampleComponent {

  selectedState: string = '';

  stateList = [
    { full: 'Ohio', short: 'OH' }, 
    { full: 'Minnesota', short: 'MN' }, 
    { full: 'California', short: 'CA' }
  ];

}
```

I just renamed the variable holding selection to `selectedState`, you can adjust this to your model